# como retornar um erro após envio de um formulario?

Tags: php, html

Como faço para retornar o `echo "Deu Erro!"`? na minha página?

//pagina-2.php

```
<form method="post" id="formulario" action="acoes/enviar-formulario.php">
   //codigo aqui
</form>
```

dentro do `enviar-formulario.php` há um update:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela set nome=\"algo\" WHERE ID=$id");

if($update === false){   
    echo "Deu Erro!";
    header("location: ../pagina-2.php");
} else{
    header("location: ../pagina-3.php");
}
```

Comment: Remova o `header()` ou mande o erro via get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é pegar a mensagem de erro e passar ela via get. Não utilize as funções mysql_* elas serão removidas no php7.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tabela set nome='algo' WHERE ID = $id";
$update = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if($update === false){   
    $erro = "Deu Erro!";
    header("location: ../pagina-2.php?erro=$erro");
} else{
    header("location: ../pagina-3.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando um parâmetro GET na URL:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['erro']) && $_GET['erro'] == '1') {
   echo "Deu Erro!";
}
?>
<form method="post" id="formulario" action="acoes/enviar-formulario.php">
   //codigo aqui
</form>
```

E no arquivo enviar-formulario.php ficaria assim:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela set nome=\"algo\" WHERE ID=$id");

if($update === false){   
    header("location: ../pagina-2.php?erro=1");
} else{
    header("location: ../pagina-3.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente passar um get ou criar uma variável de sessão e dentro do aquivo de resposta você testa. É bom usar também o **mysql_affected_rows** que retorna o número de registros atingidos pela consulta.

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela set nome=\"algo\" WHERE ID=$id");

```
if($update === false){   
    echo "Deu Erro!";
    header("location: ../pagina-2.php?mensagem=erro");
} else{
    header("location: ../pagina-3.php?mensagem=OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, uma recomendação. Para definir mensagens de erros, utilize *sessões* ou mesmo *cookies*. Para além de serem viáveis para esta tarefa, são fáceis de manipular, quando se trata de armazenar e exibir simples mensagens de erro.

## Exemplo:

```
<?php

//-Simular banco de dados
$database = array("id" => 1,
                        "usuario" => "Edilson",
                        "password" => "palavrapasse",
                        "morada" => "Desconhecido_"        
                 );
             
if(isset($_POST["cadastrar"])){
    $nome = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? (string) $_POST["nome"] : NULL;    
    $password = isset($_POST["password"]) ? (string) $_POST["password"] : NULL;
    
    if(in_array($nome, $database) && in_array($password, $database)){
        setcookie("mensagem", "Login efectuado", time()+2);
        //$_SESSION["mensagem"] = "Login efectuado";
        // Sessoes do usuario...
        // Outros
        header("Location: logado.php");    
        exit();
    } else {
        //$_SESSION["erro"] = "Usuario nao existe";    
        setcookie("erro", "usuario nao existe", time()+2);
        header("Location: erros.php");
        exit();    
    }
}                 


?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>{ Erros }</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <!-- Erros !-->
    <div id="erros">
    <?php  if(isset($_COOKIE["erro"])){ echo $_COOKIE["erro"]; $_COOKIE["erro"] = NULL; }  ?>
    <?php //echo "ola"; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Erros !-->
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Digite senha"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar"/>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Neste script por exemplo, usei uma *array* para simular o banco de dados, apesar disso funciona normalmente.

As variáveis de *sessão* ou *cookies* possuem tempo de vida, e podem ser usadas em qualquer página, desde que tenham sido definidas, como fiz no exemplo acima. Apesar de o script *PHP* estar unificado com o *formulário HTML* nada muda, mesmo se estivessem em ficheiros diferentes, a mensagem continuaria a ser impressa sem qualquer problema.